# Something used for something other than its intended purpose

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe using one thing as if it is for another purpose?  For instance, Chaplin handling his cane as if it's a pool-table cue stick, or someone using a racing hurdle as a clothesline, or a bird using a stick as a fishing pole?

Comment: In the context of medical practice, the established term is *off-label*, but it obviously cannot be used for the specific examples that the OP lists.

Answer (score 1):

A common usage would be **substitute**. Chaplin substituted a cane for a pool cue. Clothesline was substituted for the missing hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

The connotation is usually not so light, but for the cane:

> [***misappropriate***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misappropriate) -
>   to put to a wrong use.

It is more often used in that sense for ideas and not objects.

You could also say it's ***reappropriation*** in the case of the clothesline. [*Appropriate*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/appropriate) is a verb meaning "to authorize for some specific purpose," so to *reappropriate* would be to set aside for a new purpose.

Again, *reappropriation* is not generally used for objects. You hear it used to describe slurs being reconnotated into compliments.

I would not find it out of line, though, to say that the cane is misappropriated and the clothesline is reappropriated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is *repurpose*, which means adapt for use in a different purpose.

Source: Oxforddictionaries.com (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repurpose)

For example, you might say that the bird repurposed the stick to use it as a fishing pole.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that Chaplin as the Tramp **reimagined** his cane as a cue stick.

**reimagine** (v.)

> To imagine again or anew
> *especially*: to form a new conception of : RE-CREATE [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reimagine)

> Reinterpret (an event, work of art, etc.) imaginatively.
>
> *I questioned how the goddess symbolism might constitute a cultural
> resource for religious women wanting to reimagine gender relations.*
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reimagine)

---

> This is the longest set piece, or routine, Chaplin has injected into
> one of his films so far, and it's an exemplary one, examining at
> great length that most essential aspect of his art: the impulse to
> **reimagine** the universe, the absurd but wildly ingenious compulsion on the part of the Tramp, of Chaplin, **to change the meaning of
> objects, to invent new meanings**. [Kyp Harness; *The Art of Charlie
> Chaplin*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Art_of_Charlie_Chaplin/dFeDBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Chaplin%20reimagined&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover)

> Each room incorporates an object or two that has been reused,
> recycled, or **reimagined**—a decorative box embellished with old
> buttons, a vintage rowing-club trophy wired as a lamp, and so on.
> [Marie Proeller Hueston; *Farmhouses*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Farmhouses/Aw1H0Z0sVj4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20object%20was%20reimagined%20as%20lamp&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover)

> He never mentioned these assumptions explicitly, but invoked them
> through ludicrous transformations: a racist rant **reimagined** as the
> inspiration for a love ballad, a white racist **reimagined** as an
> object of sexual desire, and a victim of racial prejudice
> **reimagined** as a womanizing charmer. [H. Samy Alim et al.; *Raciolinguistics: How Language Shapes our Ideas About Race*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Raciolinguistics/Qt4oDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22A%20white%20racist%20reimagined%20as%20an%20object%20of%20sexual%20desire&pg=PA94&printsec=frontcover)