# Adjective for an item with an implied function that can't easily/readily be used for that function?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I watched somebody open a gift box with a custom made, *massive* pin badge, the sort that you would attach to clothing with a design on the front. They even said it looked like the sort of thing that you'd put on a desk, not wear, despite having the right parts to attach to clothing so it can be worn.

It made me wonder if there is an adjective for this sort of thing?

I know the word [skeuomorph](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skeuomorph) for when the *form* of an item is imitated even when not needed for it's function (like a light bulb that looks like a candle), but this is something that was the function but is not intended to be used. Like candles not intended to be lit (but could be), or a handbag that's not designed to hold items (impractically small volume), it's just an accessory. Maybe even a car that *works* but is not intended to be driven, just looked at.

I'm not inclined towards the words *display* as the pin in my first example could be displayed while attached. The handbag might be held, not just displayed in a room. I'd expect a display candle to not be lightable.

Is there a word for these sort of items?

As for example sentences, I have made these ones up to cover my purpose:

> Please don't light the candle, it's a <word> candle.

> I can't take you to the harbour in the car, it's a <word> car

> I didn't wear the pin ze sent me; however I put it on my desk as a <word> pin

> Sorry bro, can't put that in my <word> handbag. It's got a zip but there's no space inside.

> The queen never wore this into battle, it was a <word> set of armour.

After writing those, I'd be tempted to say 'show' but neither [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show) nor [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/show) list it as an adjective. I'm sort of taking it from [show car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show_car) but that seems to have a lot of other connotations that don't map over to the other examples.

Comment: We often say "The X is **purely ornamental**" when it's not intended (by the end non-user) to fulfil any practical purpose. But the pin you mention is obviously used inventively. [Something used for something other than its intended purpose](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274278/something-used-for-something-other-than-its-intended-purpose) covers repurposing.

Comment: "Show" can be used as an adjective. See here: https://www.qld.equestrian.org.au/show-horse/node/137. The word "demo" (short for demonstrator). Also, "mock-up" and "prototype."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the impression that I got was that although it could be used that way, the pin was meant *more* for display purposes.

Comment: @rhetorician but a show horse can still be practically ridden. Demo, mock-up and prototype all imply incompleteness. In fact it looks like that means a horse intended to be taken to a horse show. That doesn't fit any of my examples.

Comment: Where is the quote from, please? The pin has obviously been repurposed (whether designed to fasten kilts or merely decorate displays in cabinets). Are you talking about fully functional objects **designed** merely to collect dust, or demoted to purely ornamental status by the owner? Combining @rhetorician's and my answers, 'purely for show' covers both. But the pin example is confusing, introducing repurposing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry, which quote? All the quoted blocks are written by me. I paraphrased a YouTube video, but they don't use a single word for this.

Comment: You could use the adjective form of an adverb you used in your question:  it's *impractical/unpractical* for its intended purpose.

Comment: @DjinTonic something about "Please don't light the candle, it's an impractical candle." doesn't sound right for my purpose.

Comment: You may need different words. A very large pin may be wearable but *impractical*. A candle may be decorative only because it is a *fake/display*  candle. I can't take you on a long trip in that car because it's *unreliable* .

Comment: @DjinTonic interesting. I don't *like* that, but it may be correct

Comment: *Toy* is another candidate: something designed as a plaything, often for kids, rather than for real use; although often used for something smaller than normal. Or *plastic*, which has connotations of artificiality/fakery as in "plastic fruit", "plastic plant". Your giant pin would be *oversized*, meaning made to be too big.

Comment: I'm thinking *faux* pin or *not a working* pin.

Comment: @StuartF you made me realise by your 'plastic plant' example, that I mean more, for example, an apple tree that bears fruit that while *technically edible* doesn't taste good and can't be used for anything else - rather than a full ony *faux tree*.

Answer (score 2):

A number of adjectives could be used, depending on context, to mean 'looks like but doesn't actually work':

- [decorative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decorative)
- [ornamental](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ornamental)
- [nonfunctional](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonfunctional)
- [fake](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fake)
- [display](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/display) (attributive noun)
- [show](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show) (attributive noun, 2b)

For example,

> Please don't light the candle, it's only a **decorative** candle.

This implies that it is a candle made of wax, and if desperate you could use it as such, but it is intended just to be seen and not used up as a light. A **fake** candle would be a candle made of plastic and could never be used.

> The queen never wore this into battle - it was an **ornamental** set of armor.

'Fake' might also be used here though that is a bit tendentious, implying subterfuge rather than simple practicalities. If subterfuge is intended, then by all means use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the object can technically be used for its intended purpose, but has a drawback that limits or prevents its use, there are many possible adjectives, depending on the problem, such as:

[impractical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impractical) / [unpractical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unpractical) / [unworkable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unworkable)

[unreliable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unreliable) / [undependable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undependable)

[unwieldy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwieldy) / [cumbersome](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cumbersome) / [ungainly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ungainly) / [oversized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/oversized)

[uneconomic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uneconomical)

[loud](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loud) / [garish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garish) / [ostentatious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostentatious) / [unfashionable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfashionable) / *[ongepotchket](https://www.clevelandjewishnews.com/features/religious_life/yiddish/a-yiddish-vinki/article_e740e7f0-37e9-11e1-8a7f-0019bb2963f4.html)*

Comment: These all describe the drawback but not the item... "Please don't light the candle, it's an unreliable candle." Says nothing about why it's unreliable - it could merely be a cheap knock-off not an item only intended for it's form not function

Answer (score 0):

There is the noun "**imitation**" that is often used attributively. From Google Books:

> It’s Been an Adventure - Page 461 R. George Rea · 2017 *"Turns out it was some jerk with an imitation gun."*

> Labeling of Meat Food Products to Reflect the Inclusion of ... Page 68 United States. Congress. House.  1988 *... tomato sauce , cheese , and meat ; we strongly believe that if more than 50 percent of a characterizing ingredient , real cheese , is replaced with an imitation than the product ceases to be pizza and becomes an imitation pizza .*

> Pollen and Pollination - Page 100  Amots Dafni, ‎Michael Hesse, ‎Ettore Pacini · 2012 *Iris germanica (Iridaceae) flower with an imitation androecium mimicking stamina with white filaments and yellow thickened anthers*

Or

OED

> **Pretend** B. adj.
>
> **Designating something that is not really what it is represented as being; imaginary, imitative, make-believe, pretended. Chiefly attributive.**
>
> 1950   Chron.-Telegram (Elyria, Ohio) 2 Aug. 24/4   This is just a pretend gun.
>
> 1962   J. L. Austin's Sense & Sensibilia vii. 72   The water in toy beer-bottles is not toy beer, but pretend beer.
>
> 1996   Sunday Tel. 13 Oct. i. 39/6   The connection between pretend violence in films and on television and real killing on our streets.

Comment: I would not expect imitation/pretend candles to be lightable, for example.